# Cocoapods, add dependencies to all targets in a generic way

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, dependency-management, swift-package-manager

**App has over 20 targets.**

Every time I add a target, I need to update my podfile:

**Podfile**

```
target 'SomeNewTarget' do
    runAllPods // Block that contains all "pod ...."
end
```

**My question:**

Is there a generic way of adding dependencies to all targets? 
I would basically like to add same dependencies to all targets except test target.

**Full podifle:**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

inhibit_all_warnings!

def runAllPods
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApp

  pod 'Swinject', '~> 2.1.0'
  pod 'SwinjectAutoregistration', '2.1.0'
  pod 'IHKeyboardAvoiding', '4.0'
  pod 'SnapKit', '3.2.0'
  pod 'Material', '~> 2.10.2'
  pod 'RxSwift', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'RxCocoa', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'PureLayout'
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'
```

....More dependencies

```
end

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name == 'HydraAsync' || target.name == 'DKImagePickerController' || target.name == 'WhatsNew' || target.name == 'Closures' 
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'
        end
      end
    end
  end



target 'Target1' do
  runAllPods
end

target 'Target2' do
  runAllPods
end

target 'Target3' do
  runAllPods
end

target 'Target4' do
  runAllPods
end
...
target 'Target 20' do
  runAllPods
end
```

... More targets

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doing something like this will probably work.

```
def common_pods
    pod 'Pod1'
    pod 'Pod2'
    pod 'Pod3'
    …
end

project = Xcodeproj::Project.open "../Project.xcodeproj"
project.targets.each do |t|
    target t.name do
        common_pods
    end
end
```

For more details on this approach, check out this thread on the Cocoapod's repo:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5898